# Generating C# model classes from JSON Schema for Sabre REST API

Tags: c#, rest, sabre

We are implementing Sabre REST API to access air, hotel and vehicle content in our C# ASP.NET MVC application.

So far we have hit some issues when generating C# model classes from the JSON Schema documents provided by Sabre Dev Studio. We are using Quicktype CLI (https://quicktype.io/) to generate the model classes.

Steps we have followed so far:

1. Downloaded `OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ.jsonschema` and `OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.jsonschema` files into a folder.
2. Using PowerShell navigated to the folder and invoke `quicktype -s schema OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ.jsonschema OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS.jsonschema -o SabreAirLowFareSearch.cs`

Unfortunately it fails with the message "Error: Trying to make an empty union - do you have an impossible type in your schema?". This appears to be isolated to `OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ.jsonschema`.

Is there a tool or best practice to successfully generate C# model classes from the JSON Schema documents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've imported the NuGet Packages:

- NJsonSchema
- NJsonSchema.CodeGeneration
- NJsonSchema.CodeGeneration.CSharp

And done the code below:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NJsonSchema;
using NJsonSchema.CodeGeneration.CSharp;

namespace RunningTestings
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateClassfromJsonSchema(@"http://files.developer.sabre.com/doc/providerdoc/STPS/bfm/v410/OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ.jsonschema").Wait();
        }

        public static async Task CreateClassfromJsonSchema(string url)
        {
            JsonSchema jsonSchema = await JsonSchema.FromUrlAsync(url);
            CSharpGenerator generator = new CSharpGenerator(jsonSchema);
            string file = generator.GenerateFile();
        }
    }
}
```

Which generated the code attached on this link: **https://file.io/LlRNsf** (I'm not sure how long it will last there)

You need to perform another call for the response.

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I'm looking for @Wisdoom.